# How do I back out from a botched branch switch?

Tags: svn, branch

This is my branching routine in Subversion:

```
$ svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/foo -m "Created working branch."
$ svn switch ^/branches/foo
```

The problem is that I often forget to change to the root of the working copy, thus switching into a different directory and getting dozens of wrong changes. How do I revert such a wrong switch? What if I have some dirty files in the working copy that I wanted to commit into the new branch? Is there something like `git stash` in Subversion? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You really should just do a clean checkout in this case. The only reason you might want to do this is that you made changes in trunk without committing them. And, then the questions would be why not simply check them in and merge those changes to the branch? Switch was mainly to allow you to reuse a working directory without going through a new checkout. I'm not a great fan of `svn switch`. Too many developers use it and then realize they forgot which branch they're working on. In an age of terabyte drives, there's no reason not to have multiple checkouts.

Comment: @David: Sometimes I want those changes off the trunk because they break something for a moment. And checkouts in Subversion unfortunately also have to do with network speed, not just hard drive space. Dozens or hundreds of megabytes is still a long time to wait for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to go to the root of the working copy you're using and do an svn switch to the branch you're currently using or the one you want to go to.  This should clean up the accidental switch at the sub directory level.